# R return first substring match

Tags: r

I'm trying to categorize strings in a column of an R dataframe. Specifically, I'm looking to do the following:

1. Iterate through a list of strings
2. for each string, see if it is a substring match in a column of a dataframe
3. if yes, return the corresponding category for the first location of the substring match

for example, let's say I have dataframe1:

```
search_string = c('dan likes cake', 'molly likes cupcake', 'flanders likes berries')
```

And I want to search through a dataframe that contains lookups and categories

```
lookup_df = 
lookups: cake, cupcake, berr
categories: dessert, small dessert, fruit
```

I want to iterate through the search_strings (its a column in a dataframe) and return the following:

```
'dan likes cake' --> dessert
'molly likes cupcake' --> small dessert
'flanders likes berries' --> fruit
```

Right now I'm doing this inefficiently with nested loops.

```
for (row in 1:nrow(search_string_df)){
   search_string = #search string row

   for (row_x in 1:nrow(lookup_df)){   
      # find first substring match in lookups
      # create a new column in search_string_df with the associated category

   }

}
```

This takes a long time and I'm sure there's a better way. I'm not fluent in 'apply' and similar functions. I'm most familiar with dplyr / tidyverse syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
pat <- str_c(lookup_df$lookups,collapse = '|')

data.frame(search_string) %>%
  mutate(lookups = str_extract(search_string, pat)) %>%
  left_join(lookup_df)

 value                  lookups categories   
  <chr>                  <chr>   <chr>        
1 dan likes cake         cake    dessert      
2 molly likes cupcake    cupcake small dessert
3 flanders likes berries berr    fruit
```

---

*Data*

```
lookup_df <- data.frame(
             lookups = c('cake', 'cupcake', 'berr'),
              categories= c('dessert', 'small dessert', 'fruit'))
search_string <- c("dan likes cake", "molly likes cupcake", "flanders likes berries")
```